# Unable to use variable(s) from parent class?

Tags: java, image, inheritance, model-view-controller, polymorphism

So I need to have an example of inheritance in this code, and I am trying to get it so I instantiate `private BufferedImage image` in the parent class, and then have it take on different forms within the child classes such as Player, Enemy, and possibly Key. They will each have their specific image within them (also would this be a good example of polymorphism?). Here is the code:

```
public class Entity { //hold things such as player, and values realted to that specific entity (nice especially for organization purposes)
Image i = new Image();
MazeModel model = new MazeModel();

private BufferedImage image; //they all have images
}

class Player extends Entity{
image = i.getPlayer();

public void setPlayerStart(){
    model.setPlayerX(50); //sets the starting x position of the player's image
    model.setPlayerY(50); //sets the starting y position of the player's image
}
}
//these next two I will possibly add later if I have the time
class Enemy extends Entity{
//nothing here for now
}

class Key extends Entity{
//nothing here for now
}
```

Comment: if you want specific images according to subclasses, you must define it somewhere, right?

Comment: Yeah, I want to make it so they are all using that one private BufferedImage image, but I am not sure if this is the correct way or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`private` instances of class can't be inherited from parent to child class and you can't access in child class.

so `private BufferedImage image;` of `Entity` class can't be visible in `Player` class.

Advice: Try making this `private BufferedImage image;` as `protected BufferedImage image;` so that you can access in your child(`Player`) class as well and your instance variable will also be secure.

Comment: Did not work, it still gives me a Syntax error when I try to make image = i.getPlayer();? Is what I am doing unable to work?

Comment: and where have you defined getPlayer() method?

Comment: I think I got it to work by creating a new instance of the Image class within Player instead of trying to create it in Entity, and the extend the new instance i into Player.

Answer (score 0):

change private to public.

public BufferedImage image;

Comment: Using `protected` might be more secure than just public!

Answer (score 0):

I would use getter and setter to make it accessible.

For your case, you can make every internal values private and access it via getter and setter:

```
public class Entity {
    private Image i;
    private MazeModel model;
    private BufferedImage image;

    // initialize these values when calling new
    public Entity() {
        this.i = new Image();
        this.model = new MazeModel();
    }

    // create getter and setter
    public BufferedImage getImage(){
        return this.image;
    }

    public void setImage(BufferedImage image){
        this.image = image;
    }

    public Image getI(){
        return this.i;
    }

    // other code...
}

class Player extends Entity {
    public Player(){
        this.setImage(getI().getPlayer());
    }

    //other code...
}
```

Other than getter and setter, you need to create Constructor (public Entity() and public Player()) to initialize values.